# trigonometric functions in sqlite in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, sqlite

is there a way to get sine and cosine of a value in sqlite query in iphone sdk? when ever i tried to use sin() in my query sqlite reported that no such function exists.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks
Saurabh

Comment: As an aside, when you find yourself using SQL to perform task directly unrelated to data management, it is time to broaden your programming skills. To many people learn SQL first and then start using it like Perl, Python or Ruby. That way lays madness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQLite doesn't provide trig functions. The list of scalar functions it offers is [here](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html). You can, however, use [sqlite3_create_function()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_function.html) to make functions of your choosing accessible to SQL queries.

Comment: I does provide them behind a build configuration option, but iOS must not enable it: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_mathfunc.html